# 100% footer width has Gap

Tags: css

I seem to be having a problem with my footer growing to 100% width of the page. Currently when it expands there is a gap on each side of the footer. I tried putting the footer outside the the wrapper and inside and pretty much get the same results. I've attached my code to see if anyone can spot what im doing wrong.

[image]

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!--Begin Wrapper -->

<div id="riaandoviwrap">
<div id="riaandovi">Ria And Ovi</div>
</div>

<div id="slideshowwrap">
<div id="slideshow"><img src="images/DSC00495.JPG" /></div>
</div>

<div id="slideswrap">
<div id="slide1">SLIDE 1</div>
<div id="slide2">SLIDE 2</div>
<div id="slide3">SLIDE 3</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="content"></div>
</div>

<div id="footerwrap">
<div id="footerleft">© 2012 Ria and Ovi</div>
<div id="footerright">Share this on:</div>
</div>

</div> <!--End Wrapper -->
```

```css
body {
    background: #f7f6f6;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%
}
#riaandoviwrap {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 150px;
}
#riaandovi {
    font-family: Script;
    font-size: 75px;
}
#slideshowwrap {
    width: 950px;
    background: url(../images/slider-bg2.png);
    clear: both;
}
#slideshow {
    min-height: 350px
}
#slideswrap {
    width: 950px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #09F;
    margin-top: 6px;
    clear: both;
}
#slide1 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#slide2 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#slide3 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#contentwrap {

}
#content {

}
#footerwrap {
    min-height: 105px;
    background: url(../images/footer-bg.png);
    margin: 0px;
}
#footerleft {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
}
#footerright {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
}
hr {
    max-width: 950px
}
img {
    border: 5px solid #FFF
}
```

Comment: Try removing padding and margin from `<body>` and `<html>`.

Comment: Hi Jam, I don't have padding/margin set on body/html =/

Comment: Can you give a link to your page, or a demo page demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I've attached an image since this is just running on my local machine. The brown border at the bottom is not touching both edges of each side. there's a 10px gap on each side. I've also included my whole code, it's really simple lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set padding and margin to zero for the body tag. Althought you're not setting one manually, browsers do have a default padding/margin.

Comment: woot, that fixed it. Thanks Kory

Comment: @Ovi I said this in my comment, although I should have said "**set** the padding and margin to 0", not "**remove**". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Include a reset sheet in your document to reset all of those default styles. Recommend Eric Meyer's since its more complete:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I didn't know about the default settings browsers set, thanks for the link.